# recommended Open Source MVC 3 Projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

There some open source MVC 2 projects out there but what are your recommended open source MVC 3 projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Music shop is OK for beginner. But here are few real world application which are quite good for experienced developer.

- NopCommerce 2.0 based on MVC3 http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/releases/view/51060
- Sutekishop http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/
- Orchard proejct (MVC3, CMS) http://orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use NerdDinner

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/discussions/235392

And the 2nd project is MusicStore poject.

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

These are 2 project you find mention in most of the talks in mix and pdcs